# Chromium slow render canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, electron, nodes

Chromium slow render canvas

I record a screen using a record reader in the Chromium browser Electron App.

I take an example - https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC/blob/master/simple-demos/record-cropped-screen.html

With a render, everything is slowed down by FPS - 3

How to increase fps?
[image]